# How do I check if a cell has a select element in a Javascript loop?

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamically created table which is generated through a JS `addRow` function. I would like to loop through this table and check if the cell has a *select* element in it. If it does then I would like to push the value of the selected option to a dictionary called `ingredient_dict`.

This is what I have so far:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('selected_ingredients');
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
//table width by counting headers minus the last cell which has a delete button
var cellsCount = table.rows[0].cells.length -1 ; 

//loop through all rows (r) in table
for (var r = 1; r < rowCount; r++) { 
    //initiate dictionary for this ingredient
    var ingredient_dict = {};

    //loop through each cell (c) in row
    for (var c = 0; c < cellsCount; c++) { 
        var $cell = table.rows[r].cells[c];

         if (**CHECK IF CELL HAS A SELECT ELEMENT**) {
             $ingredient_dict["UOM"] = $cell.options[$cell.selectedIndex].value

         } else if (**CHECK IF CELL HAS INPUT ELEMENT**) {
             $ingredient_dict["qty"] = $cell.value
         } else {
             $ingredient_dict["name"] = $cell.value
         }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it matters but this is the code in my `addRow` function to dynamically create the select element:

```js
// ingredient unit of measurement drop down
var cell3= row.insertCell(2);
var unit_of_measure = document.createElement("select");
unit_of_measure.name = "unit_of_measure_select";
cell3.appendChild(unit_of_measure);
```

I'm pretty new to javascript so I apologize if my code is messy or if this is an obvious question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var doesCellHaveElement = (cell,element) => {
  return cell.innerHTML.toLowercase().indexOf(`<${element}`) >= 0;
};
```

element would be some name of tag in lowercase. For example:

```
doesCellHaveElement(cell, "select");
doesCellHaveElement(cell, "input");
```